# Looping until specific result in SQL

Tags: sql, loops

I'm looking to select all the rows at and after a specific entry.

Ex: For each cust*id, I want to loop the indicator until there is a "Yes" and then everything after that result IF THERE IS A RESULT AFTER.*

| Cust_ID | Indicator | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | 1 |
| 1 | Yes | 2 |
| 1 | Yes | 3 |
| 2 | Yes | 1 |
| 3 | No | 1 |
| 3 | No | 2 |
| 3 | Yes | 3 |
| 3 | No | 4 |

Expected Output:

| Cust_ID | Indicator | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | 2 |
| 1 | Yes | 3 |
| 3 | Yes | 3 |
| 3 | No | 4 |

Did not try loops yet -- don't know how to. Might not need them for output. I'm looking for the easiest way to do this.

Comment: "Did not try loops yet", try them, then come back and edit the question with your best effort :)

Comment: You won't be able to do anything without something to define the order of your rows.

Comment: Why isn't the cust_id=2 row in your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As @Stu pointed out: without a sorting criterion, you're busted: relational tables are *never* ordered. In a SQL database, we mean *sets*, not arrays of rows, when we say *Table* .

Having said that, try this:

```
WITH
-- your input, but enriched by a sequence
-- SQL tables are never ordered ...
indata(cust_id,seq,indicator) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'No'  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,'Yes' UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,'No'  UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,'No'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3,'Yes' UNION ALL SELECT 3,4,'No'
)
-- end of input; query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
w_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(CASE indicator WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 END) OVER (
      PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY seq
    ) AS counter
  FROM indata
)
,
grp_count AS (
  SELECT
    cust_id
  , COUNT(*) AS qty
  FROM w_counter
  WHERE counter > 0
  GROUP BY cust_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
  w_counter.cust_id
, seq
, indicator
FROM w_counter
JOIN grp_count ON w_counter.cust_id = grp_count.cust_id
WHERE counter > 0;
```

| cust_id | seq | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Yes |
| 1 | 3 | Yes |
| 3 | 3 | Yes |
| 3 | 4 | No |

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this without loops. In general, I would advise against using a loop for this. Your database will likely be able to optimize a single query much better.

Some different ways of doing it [are in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ObGQOrAd).

The simplest to follow is probably:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test t2 WHERE t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id AND t2.indicator = 'Yes' AND t2."order" <= t1."order")
ORDER BY cust_id, "order"
```

For each row in test, it just checks that there is another row that `exists` with the same `cust_id`, `indicator`='Yes', and an `order` <= to the row being considered.

Depending on the size of your data, your coding preferences, and what you know about how your DB might optimize, the other options could be considered, but the general principle of all of them is the same: Figure out the smallest `order` per `cust_id` that has `indicator`='Yes' and get the ones with `order` greater than or equal to that.

It's not clear why your cust_id=2 row is not included in your expected output, but I'm assuming that is an error. If not, you can likely adjust one of the above to add the condition to exclude it.